# KeyValuePair structure in Visual Studio 2015 UML class diagram is not generated correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uml, class-diagram

In my UML class diagram, I have one operation with KeyValuePair structure as a parameter, when I'm generating the code, the comma is interpreted as a separator between two parameters, instead of a separator between the two types of the structure.
Example: `DoSomething(pair : KeyValuePair<string,double> []):int`
And after generating: `int DoSomething(KeyValuePair<string pair, Object double>);`
Instead of: `int DoSomething(KeyValuePair<string,double> pair);`

What is the right syntax in the class diagram?

Comment: Isn't there exists an escape character? Maybe `\\`.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately it didn't work